# What is the function and use of directory "/usr/share/neofetch/ascii/distro"?

Tags: 18.04

Here are some details - I am in Ubuntu 18.04 and have found this directory `/usr/share/neofetch/ascii/distro`. I have noticed names of many distros and have viewed their text, but I am not sure how to choose one. Sorry if this sounds dumb and if I am not using the correct format of a question since I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

`man neofetch` has this:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Neofetch  is  a  CLI  system  information  tool written in BASH.
       Neofetch displays information  about  your  system  next  to  an
       image, your OS logo, or any ASCII file of your choice.
```

And from the [README](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) on the GitHub page which is worth reading to better understand the program:

> Neofetch supports almost 150 different operating systems. From Linux to Windows, all the way to more obscure operating systems like Minix, AIX and Haiku.

That would explain

> What is the function and use of directory “/usr/share/neofetch/ascii/distro”?

because the developer has tried to include ascii art for a variety of operating systems, not just yours or mine, to be displayed alongside technical data of your system.

Re.

> I have noticed names of many distros and have viewed their text, but I am not sure how to choose one.

Normally, the program detects your particular distro (and its flavor) and chooses the appropriate ascii art, if available. So you really don't need to do anything.

But, for whatever reason, you can have the ascii art of some other distro (or its flavor) or some other image altogether.

In the output below, the logo on the left represents Xubuntu even though I'm using Kubuntu:

```
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              dkb@kububb 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           ------------ 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Host: Inspiron 15-3567 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Kernel: 4.15.0-43-generic 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Uptime: 1 hour, 44 mins 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Packages: 2315 
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Shell: bash 4.4.19 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   Resolution: 1366x768 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   DE: KDE 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM: KWin 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   Theme: Breeze Dark [KDE], MyBreeze-Dark [GTK2/3] 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Icons: Breeze-dark [KDE], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Terminal: konsole 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal Font: Hack 11 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      CPU: Intel i3-6006U (2) @ 2.000GHz 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       GPU: Intel HD Graphics 520 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         Memory: 1000MiB / 7846MiB 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+. 
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`
```

The command I used is this:

`neofetch --source /usr/share/neofetch/ascii/distro/xubuntu`

based on the directions in the *man* page:

```
   --source source

      Which image or  ascii  file  to  use.   Possible  values:
      'auto',     'ascii',     'wallpaper',     '/path/to/img',
      '/path/to/ascii', '/path/to/dir/'
```

Comment: Thank you very much DK Bose for your speedy and well written reply